# Docker - Extending a container with another image?

Tags: docker, containers, extending

At my company, we have hardened containers created by the security team, and I would like to extend the hardened container with another docker image.  For example, if we have a hardened Debian container, and I want to add Apache, how do I do this?

I understand I can use `FROM` to use a base, but the examples I've seen, don't add another level of published images to an existing base, but specific commands.  Do I just go to the official Dockerhub Apache (HTTP) image and just copy and paste the commands from the github repo? I'm assuming there's a cleaner way (but not sure if there is).

For example, do I

```
FROM mycompanyprivaterepo/Debian:latest
//some command?
FROM httpd
docker build -t mynewimagewithapache
```

**UPDATE:**
After attempting via apt-get apache2 per some comments, it kept hanging on interactive questions, Solved with the help of comments using:
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM myprivaterepo/hardened-ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install apache2
```

and building via:

```
$ docker build -t hardened-ubuntu-apache
```

Comment: Generally, you would use `RUN` inside your dockerfile, and run the `apt-get` package manager to install apache. Have you tried that?

Comment: @NickODell. I haven't, I assumed there was a specific docker command for this type of activity. I'm assuming something as easy as: RUN apt-get -y install httpd?  Anything after?  Or just move to the build directly after?

Comment: `I assumed there was a specific docker command for this type of activity.` I don't think so. The only way to combine multiple images is to use a multistage build. But using a multistage build is generally a bad idea if you have some simpler alternative, like using a package manager. Have you tried something like [this example](https://gist.github.com/nickodell/bb31d507627bd28ebde3966c5ca18e9f)?

Comment: @NickODell I tried, but installation hangs with an interactive question ('Choose Geographic area'), I thought -y would handle it, but apparently not.

Comment: That's debconf. Either set debconf to non-interactive or set your timezone. https://askubuntu.com/questions/909277/avoiding-user-interaction-with-tzdata-when-installing-certbot-in-a-docker-contai

Comment: Thanks @NickODell its working now with non-interactive.

Answer (score -2):

Well, as far as I understood, you cannot use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and just

```
COPY --from=base-image /path/to/file/you-are-interested-in /path/inside/new-stage-image
```

in order to copy the required data to your preferred image. If this is the case, then *you have to* create your own Dockerfile with base image as your company **mycompanyprivaterepo/Debian:latest**, and then just create some layers on top of it in order to install required software, using RUN.

Comment: `COPY`ing individual files doesn't really work for most software packages.  If there's a binary in `/usr/bin`, plus support code in `/usr/libexec` and common modules in `/usr/share` and configuration in `/etc`, there's a lot of pieces to manually copy across.

Comment: I did not mean copying the software packages themselves, of course it will not work. I mean some configuration yaml or toml files and e.t.c